# SQLiteAssetHelper - how to insert new data to existing database with AssetHelper?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm currently coding an android application. To read a pre-existing database, I use the `SQLiteAssethelper`. It works all fine but can anyone tell me how I can insert data with the `SQLiteAssethelper`? Thank you!

Comment: `SQLiteAssetHelper` has an API that is very similar to `SQLiteOpenHelper` - most docs valid for `SQLiteOpenHelper` work also with `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
SQLiteDatabase mDb=getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("column_1", "value_1");
values.put("column_2", "value_2");
long insert_result = mDb.insert(dbSchema.table_name, null, values);
mDb.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! If I do that, the new row is not in the database. Is it necessary to update the db after inserting new data?

Comment: Can you please try incrementing your db version ie mForcedUpgradeVersion. You will have to update your db